# How do I fix this program that transforms into bit pattern all numbers that are multiply of 5 between 5 and 100 (inclusive)

Tags: java, division, multiplication, bit

How do I make this program count from 5 to 100 using for loops. 
For example it should be like this:
bit pattern representation of 5 is 101.
bit pattern representation of 10 is 1010.
bit pattern representation of 15 is 1111

I already did the code to convert decimal to binary, but I want it to start at 5 and go to 100 from multiples of 5. I know you have to put a for loop statement somewhere but don't know where.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    int x=5;
    String binaryString = " ";
    int remainder = 0;
    int decimalNumber=x;

    for (int i = 1; decimalNumber > 0; i++) {
       binaryString = String.valueOf(decimalNumber&1) + binaryString;
       remainder = decimalNumber % 2;    
       decimalNumber /= 2;
    }

    System.out.println("bit pattern representation of "+x+" is "+binaryString);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you try adding a for loop. It is `x = 5` you want to turn into a loop so why don't you try adding the loop there?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's time for a helper function:

```
public static String intToBinaryString(int number) {
    String binaryString = "";
    for (int i = 1; number > 0; i++) {
        binaryString = String.valueOf(number&1) + binaryString;
        remainder = number % 2;    
        number /= 2;
    }
    return binaryString;
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    for (int x = 5; x <= 100; x +=5) {
        System.out.println("bit pattern representation of "+x+" is "+intToBinaryString(x));
    }
}
```

Functions can help make code flexible and keep it readable.  They also give you a chance to reuse code.  They are one of my favorite forms of abstraction.

Comment: Sorry I jumped to a conclusion. I took a look at the code you posted immediately after mine and saw a couple of things the same and thought you just modified my answer slightly. I was wrong about that, down voted your answer. I then removed my comment and up voted your answer.  Normally I would write a function like you did to make it re-usable, but I was just trying to show the for-loops as requested.  The better answer would probably be a hybrid of the code I showed and what you did.

Comment: @1sand0s No harm done.  If you'd care to undelete your answer and edit it to improve it I'll be happy to remove my downvote.

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather move on. If your answer works for the asker, I'd just as soon he accept that at this point and learn my lesson about being in too much of a hurry. It also is my downfall when playing 5 minute chess (another habit). I can play really well, unless I get into a less patient mood, and then I can get on a real losing streak :-) Live and learn. Sorry to impugn your answer.

Comment: @1sand0s StackOverflows voting model is partly to blame.  Answering first is often rewarded much more then answering best.

Comment: (Why not use (`java.lang.`) `Integer.toBinaryString(x)`?)

Comment: @greybeard sure if it does what's needed.